# drag & drop using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

now I'm creating drag and drop widget, there are 3 questions as well as 3 answers. user should be able to fill only 2 answers only in any order and 3rd drop area should be disabled, the 3rd drop area can be anything in between 1 to 3 area.

After submit button is clicked the correct answers should be highlighted in Green & wrong in RED.

Please advise how to do in jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(".drop,").droppable();
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
            <div class="drag text-center"></div>
            <div class="drag text-center"></div>
            <div class="drag text-center"></div>

            <div class="drop text-center"></div>
            <div class="drop text-center"></div>
            <div class="drop text-center"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle wasn't accepting jquery UI, so I created a codepen for you.

http://codepen.io/zsawaf/pen/OWYgNg

I just have a listener for 'drop' and 'out' (built in methods for droppable). I am tracking the number of answers dropped, if they exceed the max, then I don't count them. If answers are dragged out, the dropped count decrements. As shown below:

var self = this;

```
// make questions droppable
$('.droppable').droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var $answer_dropped = $(this);

    self.dropped += 1;
    if (self.dropped <= self.max_allowed) {
      $answer_dropped.addClass('dropped');
    }
    else {
      self.dropped = self.max_allowed; // cap out at max
    }
  },
  out: function( event, ui ) {
    var $answer_out = $(this);

    if ($answer_out.hasClass('dropped')) {
      self.dropped -= 1;
      $answer_out.removeClass('dropped');
    }
  }
});
```

I'm sure you can figure out the logic from now.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: One thing I want to make that which is mentioned in my earlier. After submit button is clicked the correct answers should be highlighted in Green & wrong in RED.

Comment: @vkfjs My intention was to point you in the right direction, not to write out the entire solution ha. Regardless, right now all you have to do is have a submit button, send your answers to your backend, check if they're the right answer, then in your callback add classes to your answer element based on whether your answer is wrong or right.

Comment: You're right. I will check, thanks for your support.